# Could someone explain to me what this paragraph in The Algorithm Design Manual means? It's confusing me greatly

Tags: arrays, algorithm

[image]

I just don't understand what it means. It says all queries will be fast, except for those triggering array doubling. Why would an access query trigger a doubling of the array? I've only read that additions when it crosses the capacity mark will trigger them, but if you're accessing a certain element, surely the array has already been doubled to meet that capacity requirement, and accessing it would just be O(n)? What is this paragraph saying?

Comment: This wiki post here might help you get a better understanding of what the author is getting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array in terms of the array 'resizes' and the amortized cost involved of O(n). "Queries" in this context appear, in my opinion, to mean write operations

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. A mere read access would not cause an array doubling. By the way the complexity for a single access is even O(1) in that case.

It is hard to say what the author meant with "access" without knowing more context of this paragraph.